# How to get p12 file working on python app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-identity-toolkit

Im having trouble getting identity-toolkit fully working with Python App Engine Sandbox. The [sample provided](https://github.com/googlesamples/identity-toolkit-python) is for a non GAE Sandbox project.

In the sample project it reads `gitkit-server-config.json` from file using `os.path`. But this is not supported in GAE Sandbox. To get around this I am creating a GitkitClient directly using the constructor:

```
gitkit_instance = gitkitclient.GitkitClient(
    client_id="123456opg.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    service_account_email="my-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
    service_account_key="/path/to/my-p12file.p12",
    widget_url="http://localhost:8080/callback",
    http=None,
    project_id="my-project")
```

Is this the correct way to create the GitkitClient?

The issue now is when I try to do a password reset when running locally using `dev_appserver.py` I get the following stack trace:

```
 File "dashboard.py", line 89, in post
    oobResult = gitkit_instance.GetOobResult(self.request.POST,self.request.remote_addr)
  File "identitytoolkit/gitkitclient.py", line 366, in GetOobResult
    param['action'])
  File "identitytoolkit/gitkitclient.py", line 435, in _BuildOobLink
    code = self.rpc_helper.GetOobCode(param)
  File "identitytoolkit/rpchelper.py", line 104, in GetOobCode
    response = self._InvokeGitkitApi('getOobConfirmationCode', request)
  File "identitytoolkit/rpchelper.py", line 210, in _InvokeGitkitApi
    access_token = self._GetAccessToken()
  File "identitytoolkit/rpchelper.py", line 231, in _GetAccessToken
    'assertion': self._GenerateAssertion(),
  File "identitytoolkit/rpchelper.py", line 259, in _GenerateAssertion
    crypt.Signer.from_string(self.service_account_key),
  File "oauth2client/_pure_python_crypt.py", line 183, in from_string
    raise ValueError('No key could be detected.')
ValueError: No key could be detected.
```

Im assuming this is a problem with the .p12 file? I double checked `service_account_key="/path/to/my-p12file.p12"` and the file exists. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

FYI to others working on this in the future -

I could not get this working in python. The documentation doesn't make it clear how to get this working in app engine. In addition, dependency issues with PyCrypto made this a gcc and dependency nightmare.

I was however able to get this working in Go and there is a [semi-working example](https://github.com/googlesamples/identity-toolkit-go) online that will work with some modifications highlighted in the [issues](https://github.com/googlesamples/identity-toolkit-go/issues) and [pull request](https://github.com/googlesamples/identity-toolkit-go/pulls) pages. Good luck.